# <linearGradient> becomes very un-smooth when applying <feDropShadow> to the same <path/>

Tags: html, svg, linear-gradients, dropshadow

I made a logo consisting of 2 path elements and applied a Gradient to both of them. Works and looks good. As soon I apply a dropShadow to those same path elements, the gradient becomes un-smooth. What's the solution to this, and what causes my problem?

Here is the HTML:

```css
svg#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) scale(1.5);
}
.logo-paths {
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
width="2.86667in" height="3.13333in"
viewBox="0 0 860 940">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="top-grad" x1=".5" y1="0" x2=".5" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#151929" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bot-grad" x1=".5" y1="1" x2=".5" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#151929" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<path
stroke="black"
fill="url(#top-grad)"
class="logo-paths"
d="M 20 9.33
C 20 9.33 120 9.33 120 49.33
C 120 89.33 120 149.33 120 149.33 C 120 149.33 297 140 443.33 206
C 443.36 206 527 124.33 527 124.33 C 347.33 5.33 20 9.33 20 9.33
Z
M 120 169
C 120 169 160 169 160 209
C 160 209 160 414 160 414
C 160 414 76.88 450 61.5 469
C 61.62 469 154.75 413 258 413
C 367.25 415.75 435 447.25 435 447 C 535 489 638 489 638 489
C 638 489 769.75 489 769.75 489
C 769.75 489 686 481.75 678.5 477.75
C 690 331.75 660 267 636.25 231
C 636 230.75 548 309.2 548 309.25 C 574.73 352.36 559.75 450.25 559.75 450.25
C 559.75 450.25 502.25 435.5 425.5 404
C 425.5 404 760.25 68.75 760.25 68.75
C 760.25 68.75 820.75 8.75 840.25 9.25
C 859.75 9.75 580 9 580 9
C 580 9 660 9 660 29
C 660 49 285 384 285 384
C 285 384 280 384 280 384
C 280 384 280 189 280 189
C 280 169 120 169 120 169
Z"
/>

<path
stroke="black"
fill="url(#top-grad)"
class="logo-paths"

d="M 40.33,511.00
C 40.33,511.00 215.00,391.00 420.00,471.00
C 620.00,551.00 820.00,511.00 820.00,511.00
C 820.00,511.00 752.50,538.00 670.75,548.25
C 670.75,548.25 646.00,916.00 20.25,911.00
C 22.00,912.00 120.00,911.00 120.00,866.00
C 120.00,821.00 120.00,771.00 120.00,771.00
C 120.00,771.00 484.00,799.00 547.82,545.36
C 547.75,545.50 475.09,532.45 418.91,510.82
C 419.09,510.82 510.18,606.27 510.18,606.27
C 510.18,606.27 484.73,657.36 433.64,684.45
C 433.82,684.45 280.00,531.00 280.00,531.00
C 280.00,531.00 280.00,731.00 280.00,731.00
C 280.00,731.00 270.00,749.18 120.00,751.00
C 120.00,751.00 160.00,751.00 160.00,706.00
C 160.00,661.00 160.00,479.18 160.00,479.18
C 160.00,479.18 97.82,487.73 40.33,511.00 Z
M 610.33,717.00
C 610.33,717.00 577.00,762.00 536.33,786.33
C 535.00,786.00 660.00,911.00 660.00,911.00
C 660.00,911.00 660.00,931.00 580.00,931.00
C 500.00,931.00 840.00,931.00 840.00,931.00
C 840.00,931.00 805.00,921.00 760.00,871.00
C 760.00,871.00 610.33,717.00 610.33,717.00 Z"
    />
</svg>
```

This version looks like this:

[LOGO WITH SMOOTH GRADIENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkfcG.png)

As soon as I add this dropShadow and add this shadow to the `<path/>`´s...

```css
svg#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) scale(1.5);
}
.logo-paths {
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
width="2.86667in" height="3.13333in"
viewBox="0 0 860 940">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="top-grad" x1=".5" y1="0" x2=".5" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#151929" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bot-grad" x1=".5" y1="1" x2=".5" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#151929" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
<filter id="logo-shadow">
    <feDropShadow
    dx="0"
    dy="0"
    stdDeviation="10"
    flood-color="orange"
    flood-opacity=".3"/>
</filter>
</defs>

<path
stroke="black"
fill="url(#top-grad)"
filter="url(#logo-shadow)"
class="logo-paths"
d="M 20 9.33
C 20 9.33 120 9.33 120 49.33
C 120 89.33 120 149.33 120 149.33 C 120 149.33 297 140 443.33 206
C 443.36 206 527 124.33 527 124.33 C 347.33 5.33 20 9.33 20 9.33
Z
M 120 169
C 120 169 160 169 160 209
C 160 209 160 414 160 414
C 160 414 76.88 450 61.5 469
C 61.62 469 154.75 413 258 413
C 367.25 415.75 435 447.25 435 447 C 535 489 638 489 638 489
C 638 489 769.75 489 769.75 489
C 769.75 489 686 481.75 678.5 477.75
C 690 331.75 660 267 636.25 231
C 636 230.75 548 309.2 548 309.25 C 574.73 352.36 559.75 450.25 559.75 450.25
C 559.75 450.25 502.25 435.5 425.5 404
C 425.5 404 760.25 68.75 760.25 68.75
C 760.25 68.75 820.75 8.75 840.25 9.25
C 859.75 9.75 580 9 580 9
C 580 9 660 9 660 29
C 660 49 285 384 285 384
C 285 384 280 384 280 384
C 280 384 280 189 280 189
C 280 169 120 169 120 169
Z"
/>

<path
stroke="black"
fill="url(#top-grad)"
filter="url(#logo-shadow)"
class="logo-paths"

d="M 40.33,511.00
C 40.33,511.00 215.00,391.00 420.00,471.00
C 620.00,551.00 820.00,511.00 820.00,511.00
C 820.00,511.00 752.50,538.00 670.75,548.25
C 670.75,548.25 646.00,916.00 20.25,911.00
C 22.00,912.00 120.00,911.00 120.00,866.00
C 120.00,821.00 120.00,771.00 120.00,771.00
C 120.00,771.00 484.00,799.00 547.82,545.36
C 547.75,545.50 475.09,532.45 418.91,510.82
C 419.09,510.82 510.18,606.27 510.18,606.27
C 510.18,606.27 484.73,657.36 433.64,684.45
C 433.82,684.45 280.00,531.00 280.00,531.00
C 280.00,531.00 280.00,731.00 280.00,731.00
C 280.00,731.00 270.00,749.18 120.00,751.00
C 120.00,751.00 160.00,751.00 160.00,706.00
C 160.00,661.00 160.00,479.18 160.00,479.18
C 160.00,479.18 97.82,487.73 40.33,511.00 Z
M 610.33,717.00
C 610.33,717.00 577.00,762.00 536.33,786.33
C 535.00,786.00 660.00,911.00 660.00,911.00
C 660.00,911.00 660.00,931.00 580.00,931.00
C 500.00,931.00 840.00,931.00 840.00,931.00
C 840.00,931.00 805.00,921.00 760.00,871.00
C 760.00,871.00 610.33,717.00 610.33,717.00 Z"
    />
</svg>
```

it looks like this:

[LOGO WITH UN-SMOOTH GRADIENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9ct.png)

The shadow gets applied just like he is meant to be, but the gradients are totally messed up.

- yes, I already tried to remove every CSS-transform attribute just to test if those might have something to do with it

Anyone who can solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I really don't see the difference when I view in my browser.